# WiFi causing router crash when laptop runs off battery

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10, battery, iwlwifi

I'm experiencing a strange problem on my Lenovo Carbon X1 laptop with a fresh Ubuntu install.

The WiFi appears to work fine when the external power source is connected. However as soon as the power cord is disconnected and the machine runs off the battery, the next attempt to load a webpage causes the router to crash and reboot. Until the power cord is reconnected to the laptop, all subsequent attempts to access the web cause further crashes. As soon as the power cord is reconnected to the laptop, the WiFi starts working normally again.

There are no problems when using WiFi on Windows 8, with or without the power connected.

**Distro:**

13.10 Linux 3.11.0-14-generic

**Network adapter/driver:**

```
*-network               
description: Wireless interface
product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak]
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 96
serial: 84:3a:4b:0d:5b:04
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-14-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.113 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
resources: irq:44 memory:f0c00000-f0c01fff
```

**Syslog** immediately after disconnecting the power, followed by an attempt to load a webpage:

[thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed](http://pastebin.com/RELTtngx)

**Router model:**

Thomson TG585 v8

I guess this is a driver issue, but any remedial advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found that disabling 11n provided a workaround for the problem. `modprobe -r iwldvm iwlwifi` -> `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` -> `modprobe iwlwifi`. 

I'd still like to know why though, without this workaround in place, the wifi works fine with an external power source, but starts failing when on battery! Must be some power saving config I guess...